# get one/fist row per hour for the actual day

Tags: mysql, sql

i need to get one/the first row per hour for the actual day. I dont get it work. This is my table:

```
ID  Date        Time        Data    SID
1   2017-02-08  12:20:00    x   1
2   2017-02-09  08:20:00    x   1
3   2017-02-09  08:22:00    x   1
4   2017-02-09  08:30:00    x   1
5   2017-02-09  09:03:00    x   1
6   2017-02-09  10:20:00    x   1
```

the result should look like this:

```
ID  Date        Time        Data    SID
2   2017-02-09  08:20:00    x   1
5   2017-02-09  09:03:00    x   1
6   2017-02-09  10:20:00    x   1
```

any ideas?

Comment: You should show the query that doesn't work in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is filtering, so you can use `where`.  One method is a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.time = (select min(t2.time)
                from t t2
                where t2.date = t.date and
                      hour(t2.time) = hour(t.time)
               );
```